# Delta-Epsilon proof of $\lim_{x \to a} 2x = 2a$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Prove

$\lim_{x \to a}  2x = 2a$
Using the formal proof, not informal.

So we know

$2|x - a| < \epsilon$

We need to find some $\delta$

We only need to prove there IS **SOME** $\delta$ right? Only ONE? Is that the definition.

Prove:

$|x - a| < \delta$

We found out.

$2|x - a| < \epsilon \implies |x - a| < \epsilon/2$

So We have,

$|x - a| < \delta$ AND 
$|x - a| < \epsilon/2$

So $\delta = \epsilon/2 \space \space \space \space \space \space \blacksquare$

This completes the proof.

Is this the way to do it? I have seen though, places where you first **Assume** $|x - a| < 1$ for example.

That would be correct too right, because all we need it **ONE $\delta$ according to the definition.**

So,

Assume $|x - a| < 1 \space \space \space \space \space$  AND
$|x - a| < \epsilon/2$

But then why is the assumption that $|x - a| < 1$ for example required? 
Thanks!

Comment: For any given $\epsilon>0$ you need to find ONE $\delta >0.$ Of course, once you have found one $\delta$ any positive number smaller than it is also valid. So there are infinitely many.

Comment: @mfl, why is the assumption that $|x - a| < 1$ required?

Comment: When one uses a $\delta-\epsilon$ argument one must only be interested in small values of $\epsilon,$ from where one gets small values of $\delta.$ So $|x-a|<1$ means to take $\delta<1,$ which are the interesting values.

Answer (score 2):

This assumption is helpful when you want to find a limit of a more complicated function. I don't think you need that in this case. Generally you can do this because in a limit we are interested in finding a $\delta(\epsilon)$ for a "small" region of $x$. So you can suppose that $|x-a|<1$ or for example you can suppose that $|x-a|<\frac{1}{2}$ and then to determine $\delta$ by setting $\delta=\min\{\delta(\epsilon),1\}$ or $\delta=\min\{\delta(\epsilon),\frac{1}{2}\}$ in the second case. Hence, it not nessecary to assume that but you can do whenever you believe that it can help you. Your solution was right.